# What is the best way to manage users and companies on a project with rails in the databases engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, project-management, enterprise

I want to work in a project for enterprises. But I don't know that is most recommendable. For example, it is better that my rails app to **create a database per enterprise** when these create a account. I am thinking this because if a day the database of an enterprise have a problem not affect to other enterprises.

I want to do a project in which each time a company signs up this using your **own database**. In simple terms I do not want to cross the data, therefore, if a user has two companies for example can handle separately and stored in separate databases. This practice I have seen in the ERP software, where the person buying the product can manage your different businesses. Obviously the database will have the same design in common for all, but it's like creating two instances of the database in simple words.

Thanks

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. The way you've phrased your question, turns it into what we term a "primarily opinion based question - ie it will elicit opinion-based discussion of your situation and what people think the best way is. unfortunately, in the past, such questions often led to flame wars that tore apart the community, so we no longer allow them, and will close questions worded that way. For reference, the phrase "what is the best way" is sure to twig the opinion-based alarm-bells, which will lead to your question being closed

Comment: However - inside your opinion-based question is a non-opinion-based one which I'll paraphrase as: "How do I set up my rails app so each customer gets their own database?" Just letting you know for future question-asking here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a gem called "Apartment", which does exactly what you want:

https://github.com/influitive/apartment

Answer (score 0):

A less intensive approach than repeatedly creating databases would be to create a table for companies and a table for users and link them via a primary key (in rails that would be the id) so each user table would have a field on it "company_id" this maps to the company that the user is an employee of, if you're still worried about something happening to the database; I recommend you create backups of your database that you can restore from.

If you have any questions, feel free to comment this answer and i'll answer them for you.

Try checking out [these documents](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) about Active Record Associations in Rails

Regards,
Grant